# Siteground hosting to AWS RDS connection taking too much time

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have my backend code on siteground server and database is on AWS RDS. But when APIs are called on my server, it takes too much time to get response back from RDS to Siteground.

We tried a simple query like `"Select from TABLE where ID = 1"` and it took almost 3 seconds to return the result.

We don't want to move database on siteground so any help regarding speeding up the query time will help a lot.

Comment: I'm assuming you pinpointed the problem to network delay. Is the RDS deloyed in +- the same region as your siteground?

Comment: HI siteground region is Illinois-Chicago and AWS RDS instance is on Oregon. Can that be the issue of connection time?

Comment: I do not think that this is a network delay problem. I routinely make requests half way around the world and I do not see three second delays. Something else is causing the issue IMHO. Please provide more details on your instance configuration, results from monitoring statistics, etc. One suggestion. Create an instance in Ohio and verify that network lag is not the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your database is hosted in Oregon and your application is hosted in Illinois-Chicago, it is safe to say that the distance between these two is huge.

To achieve the fastest result, the ideal solution would be to put your app and database in the same network/location.

Since this is not an option in your case, I would advise moving your AWS application to Ohio (us-east-2).

Comment: AWS RDS did not have the region to select one from so I can match it with siteground region. And vice versa. So for now we have removed DB from RDS and put it on siteground itself.